# Unable to pass data with service in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, routes, service, subscribe

I am new to at Angular and having problem with passing data with Services. I have two components named Input and Appointments. I stored my "appointmentList" array in a DataSource file like this:

```
export const appointmentList:Appointment[] = [
    
]
```

In my inputs component creating a new object like this

```
var newAppointment = new Appointment(this.id, this.userName, this.dayName, this.intervalVal, this.procecess, this.totalPrice)
        appointmentList.push(newAppointment)
```

I have created a service and it returns an Observable method named getAppointmentList like this:

```
 getAppointmentList(): Observable<Appointment[]> {
    return of(appointmentList);
  }
```

and in my AppointmentComponent trying to fetch the appointmentList to another array like this

```
export class AppointmentComponent implements OnInit {

  appointList : Appointment[] | undefined

  constructor(private appointmentService: AppointmentService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appointmentService.getAppointmentList().subscribe(appoint => {
      this.appointList = appoint
    })
  }
  
}
```

I can confirm that in InputComponent my code pushes the newAppoitnment to appointmentList but whenever I route to Appointment component my appointmentList just resets.

Thanks all for your help!

I tried assigning productList in my service class like this:

`appointmentList : Appointment[] | undefined`

but that didn't work. I was expecting my appointmentList to be updated with new appointment objects from Input component and wanted to render them with *ngfor module.

Comment: try adding the 'static' keyword to your `export static const appointmentList:Appointment[]`

Comment: Unfortunately I got an error when I add the "static" keyword to my array, which looks like this.

'static' modifier cannot appear on a module or namespace element.ts(1044)

Comment: Can you share the full source of the above mentioned files

Comment: @robert

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l5nyy9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fappointment%2Fappointment.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `href` which caused full page reload. Instead use `routerLink` [docs](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink)

Change this `href`:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/randevular">Features</a>
```

to this use `routerLink`:

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/randevular">Features</a>
```

To verify that there is no page reload I added in AppComponent file the following:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('AppComponent -> ngOnInit');
  }
```

The above line `AppComponent -> ngOnInit` should appear only once in the console.

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-henpds?file=src/app/app.component.html)